# NextJS: after deploying, how to reload the page (F5) without being redirected to the homepage?

Tags: next.js

After I deploy to the web, every time I click reload (F5), the page returns to the home page.
I tried with url with query, after adding .html then eg: **demo.com/caseid.html?123456** the page will not be redirected to home page, but for [slug]: **demo.com/ product/[slug]** will not work. But this is the trick so it's not suitable.
How to fix that?
***Thank you guys for any answers***

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I don't know what file you need in your project, because now I don't know where the error is and the mechanism of Nextjs like that.
You can try this page: [link](https://test.innovationfurniture.com.au/), try click something you want and reload (f5) it will describe the error.